# windows 7 installation on msi gs63, kaby lake

Tags: windows-7

I installed Windows 10 multiple times because the auto-setup of drivers using the CD that comes with the package did not clean-install a lot of fronts.

Then I encountered a major problem with ssd initialization, which was discussed to have been resolved by some of the people online through windows 7 if 10 or mac OS did not help the issue. Confirmed further by MS technician who are commented below as overworked and ignorant but yes, they agreed after their own online searches.

Learned on the way that MSI provides [smart tool](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=261560.0) which didnt' work well.

So I somehow have to modify my ISO file on usb to make the motherboard recognize the installation files. [Link](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=276529.0). On my way to doing this now. Based on [this](http://file:///C:/Users/Hansun%20Lee/Desktop/temp/Win7-USB3.0-Creator-V3%20(1)/win7-usb3.0-creator-readme-v3.pdf) document that explains how to path driver.. I thought the first option wouldn't work for Windows 10 (which I'm running on now) but since the second option didn't work in the past or I didn't understand well enough, better give it a shot.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3ziQ9Vu9PA) video is relevant out of my search, but before this step, I'm told to 'Download SATA/RAID drivers from the manufacturer, put them on USB and when windows asks for the missing driver just browse to the files on the USB. Make sure you unzip them before hand' may be what I'm working on after all.

This has cost so many people their time and feeling of worthlessness/frustration, according to my search.

Comment: The Windows you should be using is Windows 10, the one factory installed. Windows 7 lacks proper support for your hardware - and it's NOT supported by the manufacturer - so you're going to have problems no matter what you try.

Comment: nothing was factory installed. And the reason for my attempt to install windows 7 is because I cannot have my ssd initialized using Windows 10. The best Microsoft office could come up with in response was to use Windows 7.

Comment: "Microsoft Office" is a software product. Probably you meant Microsoft's tech support?!? (i.e. some outsourced support with overworked and underpayed workers) And you're saying the drive is new, blank, and yet Windows 10 couldn't be installed? Or has it been used before? PS - You may have bought it without OS but that doesn't change the fact the manufacturer only supports Windows 10 for that model, period. There are NO drivers for older versions.

Comment: Precisely. I meant Microsoft's tech support- I wrote this past dawn. Typo. Seems you understood well enough tho. Windows 10 Ive been using just fine. MS GSI63 has the so-called 'smart tool' to create booting usb for Windows 7, just doesn't work on mine any better than the standard method which I googled. I havent heard about your comment before Michael, that Windows 7 is uninstallable. Not by any underworked officers at either MS or MSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://friendcom.tistory.com/17) post basically resolves the question - with a little bit more tips.

Hard to explain my steps as I have made efforts sporadically, to release the heat on my head..

Basically need to use the tools provided by the motherboard's company. In my case, MSI and its smart tool.

Requires patching of drivers, which will show up on the menu at the bottom with checkboxes when you burn the ISO file to boot USB.

In booting, BIOS set should not be LEGACY (as commonly known) but UEFI with C--.

It still requires you to convert the disk to GPT as the current setting doesn't support installation of windows 7. With my ignorance and inexperience, was lucky to get support from the blog writer, so will share here for the beginners' guide to whoever happen to encounter the same issue.

1. Click on the error message with alert sign, then press shift +f10
2. takes you to cmd, type the following in order
3. diskpart
4. list disk
5. sel disk # (number that appears to be your hard disk)
6. clean
7. convert gpt

The two commands seem unnecessary to me. But if simple 'clean' doesn't work, try both.
`create partition primary`
`format quick fs= ‘ntfs’ label=‘C’`

Then exit. Reboot.

Most likely you will get an error sign..! Something in line with secure booting.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5k3ZhO826Q) will entail which setting to fix on BIOS with no problem.

This has been the worst crack of my short life of understanding computers. But all is well now - or so it is just the beginning.;)